# After upgrade to Material 15 my checkboxes and their labels are not in line

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've updated my Angular/Material project to 15 and after getting through the update guide, I've noticed that my checkboxes are misaligned with the labels.

Example:

[image]

How can I make it back so they will be on the same line?

I've tried applying

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.checkbox-density(-1);
```

as they're suggesting in the guide, but didn't work.

Comment: Same here, did you find a solution?

Comment: Also have the same problem, mat.checkbox-density(-1) is not working